# How to divide doubles in an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, division

I have in array with some doubles in them. I want to divide them, for example with an array that contains 6.0, 3.0 and 2,0 the result should be 1 (6/3/2). I wrote the following code:

```
System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to divide? ");
int division = input.nextInt();
double[] divisionArray = new double[division];

for(int i = 0; i < division; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter your " + (i + 1) + ". number: ");
    divisionArray[i] = input.nextDouble();
}
for(int k = 0; k < division; k ++) {
    double resultDivision = divisionArray[k] / divisionArray[k + 1];
}
System.out.println("Result: " + resultDivision);
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I get the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2` I'm a complete java beginner. Could anyone help me out? Thanks

Comment: You are declaring the `resultDivision` variable inside the final loop, so you can't then refer to it after.

Comment: Where you declare the variable matters. You can only use it in the scope in which its is defined.

Comment: To whomever cast the `close` vote on this question - this question is not in any way off-topic. OP clearly states the issue and what the code should do, including an example. I wish all beginner questions looked this way.

Comment: @Malt I cast the close vote because "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." The question doesn't contain a specific problem or error, so, according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, it's off-topic.

Comment: @Malt it's *very* close to being a really nice question but it's missing the one thing needed to make it useful to future users - the problem statement! Brian for questions here you need to include the actual error or incorrect output that you are seeing - "that doesn't seem to work" isn't going to be something future users with the same problem can find, which is the bar we set on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll make sure to do that the next time I have a question

Comment: @Brian don't apologize, [edit] instead :)

Comment: @Brian that's not the actual problem you should have in the code shown: [it doesn't even compile](http://ideone.com/TRerv1).

Comment: @AndyTurner You're right, it doesn't contain a specific problem or error. But the question is perfectly understandable and answerable. I'm sure that a Google software engineer such as yourself could have easily figured out and helped OP with his problem. Closing a user's first question because he didn't dot all his i's and crossed all his t's seems overly pedantic to me when the question can be easily edited. This kind of welcome is why we drive away good people (https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/54f62f/the_decline_of_stack_overflow/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to divide? ");

        int division = input.nextInt();
        double[] divisionArray = new double[division];

        for(int i = 0; i < division; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter your " + (i + 1) + ". number: ");
            divisionArray[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }

        //remember the first value and divide it trough the second, 
        //third, fourth and so on...
        double result = divisionArray[0];
        for(int k = 1; k < division; k ++) {
            result = result / divisionArray[k];
        }
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
```

Comment: "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day; teach him fishing and you feed him for a lifetime."

Comment: I'm confused, @Bálint - are you saying this answer is fish or a fishing lesson?

Comment: Fish, you gave him the working code without any explanation

Comment: @Bálint maybe say that directly then? :)

Comment: @Bálint Yes you are correct, sry. Malt's answer should be the approved one.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has three issues.

1. `resultDivision` is defined within the scope of the `for` loop, so it's not visible afterwards, when you print the result.
2. With #1 fixed, you'll get an `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception because the second `for` loop tries to access `divisionArray[k+1]`.
3. You don't check the arguments that the user gives you. What if a user specifies that it wants to divide `-5` numbers? Your code will try to create an array with a length of `-5`, causing an `Exception`. Also, What if a user wants to divide by zero? Are you fine with that?

Here's a slightly better version:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int division = 0;
do {
    System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to divide? ");
    division = input.nextInt();
} while (division <= 0);

double[] divisionArray = new double[division];
for (int i = 0; i < division; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter your " + (i + 1) + ". number: ");
    divisionArray[i] = input.nextDouble();
        if (divisionArray[i] == 0 && i>0) { // Remove this if you want to allow the user to divide by zero. Entering zero as the first argument is legal
    System.out.println("Zero is an illegal argument, please enter a different number");
        i--;
    }
}
double resultDivision = divisionArray[0];
for (int k = 1; k < division; k++) {
    resultDivision = resultDivision / divisionArray[k];
}
System.out.println("Result: " + resultDivision);
```

Good luck.

Comment: I was not far enough to think about cases that should not happen, but now that I have that problem fixed this is the next thing I'm tackling!